# How to edit a yaml file with PyQt4 GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, yaml

So I'm trying to create a simple GUI that takes a yaml file and edits it through PyQT. 
Let's say that yaml contains {example: "Helloworld"}

I'm having trouble even displaying the yaml in the GUI box.

So I have the GUI text box written in python:

```
import yaml
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class GUI(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        msg = QtGui.Qlabel("This is a test message")
        self.msg.move(60, 20)

        self.addedLine = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        textBox = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)

        textBox.move(60, 100)
        self.addedLine.move(60, 40)

        textBox.textChanged[str].connect(self.onChanged)

        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QLineEdit')
        self.show()

    def onChanged(self, text):

        self.addedLine.setText(text)
        self.addedLine.adjustSize()        

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and this is just a simple function for displaying the yaml data

```
def displayYaml():
    yamlDoc = open("yaml.yml",'r')
    data = yaml.load(yamlDoc)
    yamlDoc.close()
    prettyData = yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False)
    return prettyData
```

So can I add this displayYaml function to the GUI class? or do I have to make it a separate file and import it? I tried the displayYaml code without the function and tried writing it directly into initUI but that doesn't work and I get the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'yaml' referenced before assignment
```

In the end I want it to 
1. display the yaml doc. This would be a fixed message line. 
2. have a separate message line and text change box, which I already did
3. overwrite the yaml doc with whatever is the input in the textchange box.

Comment: You can move `displayYaml` into your class. You could have it as a separate function in the class that gets called on an event (button clicked, etc) or you could have initUI run it.

Comment: That didn't quite work either, so honestly I'm a but out of ideas.

Answer (score 5):

```
import sys, yaml
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.plainTextEdit = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Load Yaml")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.setLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.loadYaml)

    def loadYaml(self):
        fileName = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File","/home/some/folder","Yaml(*.yaml);;AllFiles(*.*)"))
        f = open(fileName)
        getData = yaml.safe_load(f)
        prettyData = yaml.dump(getData, default_flow_style=False)
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(str(prettyData))

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Try this code

Comment: Thanks! So this solves the loading the data problem... but can I make two buttons: "load yaml" and "save yaml" and whatever is in the PlainTextEdit window overwrites the current yaml?

Comment: Its totally upto you :)